# Контекстное меню на элементе списка

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма поиска. Хочу добавить контекстное меню на элементе, который является результатом поиска(например на фамилии работника при нажатии правой кнопкой мыши открывалось меню). Не знаю как выделить элемент и привязать к нему contextMenu, думаю что надо св-во GetFocusedRowCellDisplayText, но не уверен.

Comment: Что из себя представляет "результат поиска" - `DataGridView`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да

Answer (score 0):

Добавляем **contextMenuStrip** на форму
**dataGridView1** Свойства **contextMenuStrip:contextMenuStrip1**

```csharp
        private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int selRowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        }
        private void openNameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Здесь выполняем свой код
        }
```